# AllowAnonymous annotation doesn't prevent inlog requirement

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, annotations

I currently have a medium sized web application, built in .NET with MVC & C#. For almost all of the pages, one has to be authorized, so I put the **[Authorize]** annotation at the top to do this.

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{ ...
```

Though for one page the user should access it without being authorized. How can I do this? I've tried putting the **[AllowAnonymous]** annotation at the top, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm still being redirected to the login page.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(Guid? identifier)
{
```